# Which arguments are passed through session initialization?

Tags: lotus-notes

Code accessing Lotus Notes C++ API often starts with:

```
LNNotesSession session;
session.Init(argc, argv);
```

Which kinds of 'argv' is there? Could I pass id file and password through 'argv'?

Answer (score 1):

The name of the variable argc stands for "argument count"; argc contains the number of arguments passed to the program. The name of the variable argv stands for "argument vector". A vector is a one-dimensional array, and argv is a one-dimensional array of strings. Each string is one of the arguments that was passed to the program.

You can pass strings in argv. How to log inusing the API is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789178/how-to-authorize-lotus-notes-database-by-c-api/7790421#7790421).

Comment: Using nextpwd.dll requires to copy dll to Lotus Notes folder and modify Notes.ini. I would like to find more indepently way to login.

Comment: I see what you want to do, however I could not find any other reference to a way to log in using the api. Using Java it would be easy: NotesFactory.createSession((String)null, (String)null, passwordString)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only useful info that you can pass through the argc and argv in the LNNotesSession.Init call is the path to the notes.ini file.  I.e., a user can run Notes with an arbitrary notes.ini file using a command line that looks like this:

C:\Notes\Notes.exe =C:\SomeFolder\notes.ini

To get the API to use an arbitrary notes.ini, you would set argv[0] to a pointer to the name of your program, and argv[1] to a pointer to a string like "c:\SomeFolder\notes.ini".

The Notes client does accept some other command line arguments, but I don't believe any of them are useful for the API.  I'm not sure about the Domino server.  The C++ API doc alludes to the possibility that there are some useful command line arguments for Domino servers on Unix platforms, but I'm not aware of what those might be.